# Android: how to enable updates in LocationListener

Tags: android, gps, updates

I stop the updates with `lm.removeUpdates(Loclist);`

How to enable the GPS updates?

I was searching in Google and I was trying some other methods but nothing help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried to stop the activity with finish(); and then go back again in the old activity.Maybe I was thinking to reset the LocationListener but without success.

Comment: Did you try to follow the official guidelines? http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html - this is how to enable updates: `mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);`

Comment: Yes I tried with `lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER,180,1,Loclist);` but is not helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are just trying to get the GPS location

try to do this, put this code on method onResume()

```
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 1, Loclist);
```

and `lm.removeUpdates(Loclist)` on method onPause()